# Which scriptures are used to justify ignoring feelings?

Tags: biblical-basis, faith, obedience, emotions

Having attended a number of churches, at least one of which claimed to be 'non-denominational,' I have been subjected to listening to this teaching, which I have seen used to try to convince people that they should completely ignore all their feelings, whether they be feelings of physical or emotional pain or of joy, and simply adhere to the teachings of the Bible regardless. At worst, this means someone feeling terrible pain and sickness being told they have been healed by the stripes of Yeshua and just to thank Him for that without changing anything else in their lives.

One scripture I've heard quoted to support such a reading is:

> For we walk by faith, not by sight. (2 Cor 5.7)

I'm just wondering if anyone knows of any others and furthermore, if anyone knows of any examples of the reasoning from the scriptures used by people who claim to believe the Bible and read it in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So then faith comes by hearing, and hearing by the word of God.
>
> Romans 10:17
>
> The heart is deceitful above all things, and desperately wicked: who
>   can know it?
>
> Jeremiah 17:9

As Christians we should not base our faith on how we feel that day because, as it says in Jeremiah 17, and as we all know, our feelings are fickle and deceptive. We should base our faith upon the Word of God and the promises that God makes in it.

As far as I have come to know, many charismatic churches use people's feelings to basically get them to give up large sums of money. What you describe, I have never really seen. However, it is Biblical not to rely on your feelings, but only on the solid Rock, Jesus Christ.

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson brother, I'm not sure you finished your thought there... I don't understand.

Comment: What about the woman who had the issue of blood which was stopped when she touched Yeshua: 'Immediately the fountain of her blood was dried up, and she felt in her body that she was healed of the affliction.' Does this not show at least that what people feel *can* be an accurate indication of what has really happened, if not that what they feel is *always* an accurate indicator?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be honest, my reading of the first scripture is that it says nothing about whether or not feelings agree with The Word of God. In response to the second scripture, I would point out that a) it could be that this refers to the state of men's hearts before The New Covenant was established, which has surely changed that situation for those who enter into it and continue to walk in it b) in reference to their experience with Yeshua on the road to Emmaus, the disciples mentioned that their hearts burned within them, by which they should have known it was Yeshua talking.

Comment: The latter is clear evidence that the feelings experienced within the heart agree with The Word of God, rather than oppose it.

Comment: I get into my reading of the scriptures you've quoted because you do the same, but that is against the agenda of the people in charge of this website, whom I don't seek to offend if I can help it. You have provided sciptures as requested though: thanks for that.

Comment: As it stands I wouldn't be able to accept this answer, as it breaks the instruction of the people who run the site that one shouldn't express one's own reading of The Bible: only quote those of others. I would happily talk to you about my and your readings of The Bible, but this is discouraged and frowned upon on this site.

Comment: My answer speaks more about emotions than it does physical feeling, which I believe are two completely different things, though not disconnected from one another, however I have not been able to read more about this and give you a better answer.

Comment: My reading of scripture is that it's full of emotion and feeling. I agree we are to keep the Word of God. Can feelings go against scripture? Maybe. But they can also be in line, as I've pointed out with examples. Actually I think I was unfair to criticise your answer for expressing your reading of scripture, even though it is discouraged on this site. I guess I'll have to think about accepting an answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

These are some verses used as you described;

2 Corrinthians 4;18

> While  we look  not  at  the  things  which  are  seen,  but  at  the 
>   things  which  are  not  seen:  for  the  things  which  are  seen are
>   temporal,  but  the  things  which  are  not  seen  are  eternal.

Hebrews 11;1

> Now  faith  is  the  substance  of  things  hoped  for,  the  evidence
>   of  things  not  seen.

There  are  several  other verses similar to  these.  A  verse  often  overlooked  is  James 2;20

> But  wilt  thou  know,  O  vain  man,  that  faith  without  works 
>   is  dead.

Hebrews  11  gives  examples  of  people  who  have  overcome  by  faith.

The  example  of  the  woman with  the  issue  of  blood  clearly  makes  the  point  of  James.  She  acted  on  her  faith,  she  didn't  stand  idly  in  the  crowd.

As  for  our  emotions,  they  to  are  a  result  of  some  action.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for every church but, what comes to mind here for me, and i hope it answers this question is.

Romans 8:5-8 5 Those who live according to the flesh have their minds set on what the flesh desires; but those who live in accordance with the Spirit have their minds set on what the Spirit desires. 6 The mind governed by the flesh is death, but the mind governed by the Spirit is life and peace. 7 The mind governed by the flesh is hostile to God; it does not submit to God’s law, nor can it do so. 8 Those who are in the realm of the flesh cannot please God.

When it talks about the mind here it is the word phroneó when used in the context of romans 8:5 and 6 i found this definition, to direct one's mind to a thing, to seek or strive for; to seek one's interests or advantage; to be of one's party, side with him, Which is why i like the niv translation of being governed by the flesh or governed by the spirit. Now in ancient times emotions were thought to come from the heart, we now know they come from the brain (or maybe the stomach we have gut feelings). If we consider that the brain is a part of our flesh than we can begin to see that emotions are also a product of our flesh. Now although physical feelings like fire being hot, or whether we are sick or not are very beneficial, emotion is a little different. Acting from anger, sadness, fear or even happiness can have huge negative impacts on our lives and are an example of being governed by the flesh.

Galatians 5:22-23 But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, forbearance, kindness, goodness, faithfulness, 23 gentleness and self-control. Against such things there is no law.

Although most people think of things like Joy and peace as emotions they are something totally different, and are given to us by the spirit. Those who are governed by the spirit live there lives from those fruits and not from the circumstantial emotions of the flesh. I hope that is clear enough to understand.

Comment: Well thanks for your reply.  I mean I disagree with the idea that we are supposed to ignore feelings, but I'll probably leave it at that for now ha, except to clarify that when I say feelings, I'm not just talking about emotions, but also physical feelings, such as sickness or physical pain for example.